# ASP.net project to .exe file

Tags: asp.net, exe

I have an ASP.net project file.

How can I convert this file to an .EXE file?

Is it possible for remote user to use the .EXE file?

Comment: what do you mean here? to make it exe, run it and see your pages ?

Comment: It is not possible, but if you describe what you're after in more detail, maybe we can help you.

Comment: ASP.Net is a web framework that renders HTML pages. It doesn't make any sense to convert a web site to a .exe file. What exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @EricAndres I have done an ASp.net project, I need to show this to my client. What should I do?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I have done an ASp.net project, I need to show this to my client. What should I do?

Comment: Deploy it to a server. Your laptop could serve in a pinch.

Answer (score 3):

No. An ASP.NET application is a web application that must be served to the web from a web server - usually IIS. It cannot be used through an .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net = Web application (You can't run it as an EXE)

For standalone application.
Choose File->New Project->Visual C#->Windows->Console Application

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys when I posted this question 4 years back I dint have lot of experience in programming/ASP.Net, I find this question very silly and not correct. I think at that time I meant to ask the below question

"I have got an ASP.Net application how can I deploy it to give a demo to the team"

I would like to either edit or close this question. What should I do now?